# App crashes when calling ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync on iOS 13pro, Ipad pro 16.3.1

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I am trying to launch camera on real divece(android working well, issue only with ios). Ios/ipad app exit when hit the function. Any smart advice how can i pass it?

````
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import * as Device from "expo-device";

 const askPermission = async () => {
    const permission = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (permission.status === "granted") {
      return true;
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    if (permission.status !== "granted") {
      const newPermission = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (newPermission.status === "granted") {
        return true;
      }
    }
  };
  const onPickFiles = async () => {
    const isNotDevice = !Device.isDevice;
    if (!(await askPermission())) {
      Alert.alert(
        "Camera permission",
        "Please alow camera device to take photo to proceed",
        [
          { text: "Yes", onPress: () => console.log("Yes Pressed") },
          {
            text: "No",
            onPress: () => console.log("No Pressed"),
            style: "cancel",
          },
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
      return;
    }
    const method = isNotDevice
      ? ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync
      : ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync;
    let result = await method({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      presentationStyle: ImagePicker.UIImagePickerPresentationStyle.FULL_SCREEN,
      allowsEditing: false,
      ...(isNotDevice && {
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
      }),

      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      onUpload(result.assets);
    }
  };```
````

expo env

```
 expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 12.6.3
      Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 18.16.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.3/bin/yarn
      npm: 9.5.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/npm
      Watchman: 2023.01.23.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.12.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.5, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9514443
      Xcode: 13.4.1/13F100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~47.0.12 => 47.0.14 
      react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0 
      react-native: 0.70.8 => 0.70.8 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      eas-cli: 3.9.2
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Comment: What is the exception message you receive?

Comment: thank you for your punch, i was lazy to inspect dev version, by  investigation the warnings i found potential solution by using correct permission request 
```const permission = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);``` - working fine on dev with expo, however when testing the prod version with testflight on open camera show up modal to request permission and the app in same second exit, making me crazy - feel its some small bug wich bothering me for smooth release

Answer (score 0):

just restart build and for some reason no more crashes